# Attach Auth0 access token as request header for GraphQL ApolloClient in NextJS app

Tags: next.js, apollo, auth0

I have a NextJS v13 frontend and a NodeJS/GraphQL backend. I wrap my entire next app in an `ApolloProvider` as per the Apollo docs https://www.apollographql.com/blog/apollo-client/next-js/how-to-use-apollo-client-with-next-js-13/

I want to be able to grab the user's Auth0 access token, and attach it to the request headers inside of the Apollo client. That way every GraphQL request will include the access token.

To do this I'm using an `authLink` and concatenating it with the typical Apollo `serverLink`. But when I go to instantiate the `authLink`, I'm unable to run any `await` calls, which is necessary to go fetch the Auth0 access token.

It works fine if I pass in a hard-coded value, but I'm not able to actually go and fetch the access token using async/await.

As soon as I add that I get an error screen like this:

[image]

How can I grab the access token and pass it in the headers?

Here's my `_app.js` file:

```
import StyledEngineProvider from '@mui/material/StyledEngineProvider';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import posthog from 'posthog-js';
import { PostHogProvider } from 'posthog-js/react';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import ApolloProvider from '../providers/ApolloProvider';
import UserProvider from '../providers/UserProvider';
import Styles from '../styles';

// Check that PostHog is client-side
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  posthog.init(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_POSTHOG_KEY, {
    api_host: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_POSTHOG_HOST,
    // Enable debug mode in development
    loaded: (posthog) => {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') posthog.debug();
    },
  });
}

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Track page views
    const handleRouteChange = () => posthog.capture('$pageview');
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);

    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <ApolloProvider>
        <PostHogProvider client={posthog}>
          <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
            <ThemeProvider theme={Styles}>
              <Layout>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
              </Layout>
            </ThemeProvider>
          </StyledEngineProvider>
        </PostHogProvider>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </UserProvider>
  );
};

export default App;`
```

This file imports my ApolloProvider, which instantiates the client:

```
'use client';
import { ApolloLink, HttpLink } from '@apollo/client';
import {
  ApolloNextAppProvider,
  NextSSRApolloClient,
  NextSSRInMemoryCache,
  SSRMultipartLink,
} from '@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/ssr';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/link-context';

const makeClient = () => {
  const env = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV;
  const linkUri =
    env === 'local'
      ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_LOCAL_API_URL
      : process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REMOTE_API_URL;
  console.log('linkUri', linkUri);

  const accessToken = 1;
  const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
    // const accessToken = await getAccessToken();
    // const session = await getSession();
    // console.log('session', session);
    console.log(accessToken);
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    };
  });

  const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: linkUri,
  });

  const serverLink = authLink.concat(httpLink);

  return new NextSSRApolloClient({
    cache: new NextSSRInMemoryCache(),
    link:
      typeof window === 'undefined'
        ? ApolloLink.from([
            new SSRMultipartLink({
              stripDefer: true,
            }),
            serverLink,
          ])
        : serverLink,
  });
};

export default function ApolloProvider({ children }) {
  return (
    <ApolloNextAppProvider makeClient={makeClient}>
      {children}
    </ApolloNextAppProvider>
  );
}
```

My downstream pages then make GraphQL requests as usual, using the `useQuery` hook.

Would greatly appreciate any help here!

- I tried grabbing the access token through a `useEffect` in the component and passing that into the `makeClient` function, but that didn't work
- I tried grabbing the access token directly in the `makeClient` function, but that errors out
- I tried setting headers via a middleware file, but that didn't seem to get set properly as it never arrived in my NodeJS backend